# Docker SQL Server exception

Tags: sql-server, docker, asp.net-core-webapi

I had a SQL exception while I was running my .NET Core 3.1 Web API project in a Docker container

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connection

```html
version: "3.7"

services:
  
  SQLServer:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
    container_name: SQLServer
    networks:
      mynetwork:
        aliases:
          - db1.internal.prod.example.com

  CRUD_JSON_API:
    image: koccan9/crud_json_api:samplev3
    container_name: "crud_json_api_sample"
    restart: on-failure
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: CRUD_JSON_API/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - SQLServer
    networks:
      mynetwork:
        aliases:
          - web1.internal.prod.example.com

volumes:
  mssql-server-julie-data: {}

networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge




version: '3.7'

services:

  SQLServer:
environment:
  - MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=xxx
  - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
  - MSSQL_PID=Developer
ports:
  - "1433:1433"
volumes:
  - ./data/mssql:/var/opt/mssql3
expose:
  - 1433
  
  CRUD_JSON_API:
links:
  - SQLServer
environment:
  - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
  - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:80
  - ConnectionString=${IDENTITY_DB:-Server=SQLServer;Database=DEV_CRUD_JSON_API;User Id=sa;Password=xxx}
ports:
  - "5000:80"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that In SQL Server configuration is correct.  Additionally check this link: [mssql-docker-issues](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/581)